# How to use Excel Object Model in Access Query Expression?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am moderate to advanced user of Microsoft Excel, but very new to Microsoft Access (2010 version). What I am trying to do is use Excel functions in an Access Query Expression. So far, I've researched how to set Access to reference the Microsoft Object Model by going to Create/Module/Tools/References and then selecting the Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library.

From there, I went to my Query (Design View) and attempted to add an expression in the Field row to calculate the distance between two points. As a test, I typed:

```
Distance: Excel.WorksheetFunction.ACOS(50)
```

I thought this would work, but once I closed, saved the Query, and reran the Query I received the following error:

```
Undefined function 'Excel.WorksheetFunction.ACOS' in expression
```

I've done some Googling to determine why this isn't working, but have been unsuccessful. I'm not sure if Access allows you to reference Excel directly from the expression. Or, perhaps my syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a simple function in VBA (in Access) that calls the Excel function you want to use:

```vb
public function myTestFunction(x as double) as double
    myTestFunction = Excel.WorksheetFunction.ACOS(50)
end function
```

Use this function in your query:

- If you use the query design grid:

  Simply write the function in a column and put the column name of the column that holds the input value as the argument. If you want to put an alias to the column, write the alias before and use `:`; something like this: `columnAlias: myTestFunction([OtherColumn])`
- If you're writing your query using SQL:

  Write your query as usual; use the function like any other function available in SQL:

```sql
select [OtherColumn], myTestFunction([OtherColumn]) as function
from  [YourTable]
```

Comment: Thanks. Once I create the function how do I use this function in the query?

Comment: Thanks, I did what you said. When I try to rerun the Query I am asked to Enter Parameter Value?

Comment: @Chris2015 of course, the column name must exist in the tables defined in the `FROM` clause of the SQL instruction (or the ones you've dragged to the design grid)

Comment: If I wanted to use a function to sum a column in one of my tables for instance what would that look like? myTestFunction = Excel.WorksheetFunction.SUM(access table.column)? I am sure Access has its own sum feature, but just as an example. Thanks again!

Comment: You're migrating from Excel to Access... so... you must change the way you think on your data: In Excel you have unlimited freedom to sum rows, columns and non-contiguous ranges. But in Access (or other relational database management systems) your data is stored in a much more restricted: you can perform operations on data on the same row, but if you want to sum the data of a column, you must *aggregate* the data (using `GROUP BY` and aggregate functions). Consider getting a good book or online tutorial on Access and databases